# How to get Overlap Function to run

Tags: javascript, p5.js

My overlap function will not run for me and when added to my sketch it turns the sprites into still images. The console is telling me that overlap can only be used between sprites and groups, but I am using a sprite so I am unsure how to resolve the issue. What would be the was to resolve this?

```
let hobbitAttackSprite;
let martialHeroSprite;

let runAnim;
let idleAnim;
let jumpAnim;


function preload() {
  hobbitAttackSprite = loadAnimation('sprites/Bringer-of-Death_Idle_0001.png', 'sprites/Bringer-of-Death_Idle_0008.png');
  //all of the animations will be loaded in like attack1, attack2 etc. We need to rename these. So, on our desktop or wherever the images are saves we can select all of the images and go to file rename and rename them like attack_00001. All of the file names from the 1st to 17th will now load.
  let runSheet = loadSpriteSheet("sprites/Martial_Hero_Run_8.png", 200, 200, 8);
  let idleSheet = loadSpriteSheet("sprites/Martial_Hero_Idle_8.png", 200, 200, 8);
  let jumpSheet = loadSpriteSheet("sprites/Martial_Hero_Jump_4.png", 200, 200, 8);
  
  runAnim = loadAnimation(runSheet);
  idleAnim = loadAnimation(idleSheet);
  jumpAnim = loadAnimation(jumpSheet);
}


function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
   // create martialHero sprite
  martialHeroSprite = createSprite(windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2, 32, 32);

  // add animations to martialHero
  martialHeroSprite.addAnimation("idle", idleAnim);
  martialHeroSprite.addAnimation("run", runAnim);
  martialHeroSprite.addAnimation("jump", jumpAnim);

  // scale sprite
  martialHeroSprite.scale = 1;
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  animation(hobbitAttackSprite, windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2);
  drawSprites();
  checkForInteractions();
}
function checkForInteractions() {
  
  if (martialHeroSprite.overlap(hobbitAttackSprite)) {
    text("Hello Bringer of Death, Let's Battle!", windowWidth/1.5, windowHeight/1.5);
  }
}
function keyTyped() {
  if (keyCode == 65) {
    // change from idling to running
    martialHeroSprite.changeAnimation("run");

    // sprite is facing the left
    martialHeroSprite.mirrorX(-1);
    
    // move martialHero to the left
    martialHeroSprite.velocity.x = -7;
    
  } else if (keyCode == 68) {
    // change running 
    martialHeroSprite.changeAnimation("run");
    
    // martialHero facing right
    martialHeroSprite.mirrorX(1);

    // move martialHero to the right
    martialHeroSprite.velocity.x = 7;
    
  } else if (keyCode == 32) {
    // make martialHero jump
    martialHeroSprite.changeAnimation("jump");
  }
}

function keyReleased() {
  if (keyCode == 65 || keyCode == 68 || keyCode == 32) {
    martialHeroSprite.velocity.x = 0;
    martialHeroSprite.changeAnimation("idle");
  } 

}
```

Thanks in advance!
-Riley

Comment: Link to the code: https://editor.p5js.org/Riley_F/sketches/1oilo6QgZ

Answer (score 1):

addAni to a sprite adds Animation to the specified Sprite, after
you can use overlap

```
hobbitAttacksSprite = new Sprite(250, 80, 120);
hobbitAttacksSprite.addAni('npc', 'assets/yourSeven.png', 7);
```

https://p5play.org/learn/sprite_animation.html?page=2 and other documentation https://jdjohnsonmedia.com/thesis_site/prototype_game/libraries/p5.play-master/docs/classes/Sprite.html

Comment: Could you be more specific on this? It is not working for me.